# Git workflow architecture for opensource project

Tags: git, github, version-control

Our company has started working as a contributer for an open source project. The versioning system used will be Git . We have already forked the project and therefore already have the remote repository. I want a local repository and each develeper should have a separate branch of the local repository . They would make changes and commit to their branch and later push to the local repository. After all changes , the local repository changes will be pushed to remote repository and from there pull request will be created. This is my intended workflow in layman terms. How do i go about it in Git?

Comment: If the remote repository is on github then why not just use that instead of working on a local repository too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common process to contribute for a github repo as below (assume your team want to contribute to a github repo for `master` branch):

1. Fork the github repo your team want to contribute.
2. Create a `develop` branch for the fork repo.
3. Each developer works in his separate local branch, after finish his work, merge his local branch to `develop` branch and then push `develop` branch to fork repo (or push his local branch to fork repo and then create a pull request to merge his separate branch into `develop` branch).
4. After your whole team finish the work, create a pull request to merge `develop` branch into `master` branch.